# Hydrating Tweets

Tags: r, json, tweets

everyone!
I'm doing research using COVID 19 Tweets. I've downloaded some COVID 19-sourced tweets from https:/zenodo.org/record/3970127#.Xy12rChKiUk. However, the data only includes the Twitter ID. Does anyone know how to hydrate the data in RStudio and get the JSON file with the text? It seems I can use the Twarc
package, but I'd like to do the whole process in the R environment, not in Python.

Comment: What do you mean by "hydrate" the data?

Comment: Hi, "hydration" is the process of getting the tweet text when you only have the unique id of that tweet. Twitter only allows sharing of tweet ids but not full tweets (cf. https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/PDI7IN)

Comment: You might find "Hydrator" helpful: https://github.com/DocNow/hydrator. - It is a standalone application for hydrating tweets that gets you the data as .csv, which you then can use in R.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for an R package to grab tweet texts. Unfortunately, package recommendations are considered off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a tad late but here goes: Twarc's package description includes a mention of a similar package for R--which would answer OP's question.

"For R there is academictwitteR. Unlike twarc, it focuses solely on querying the Twitter Academic Research Product Track v2 API endpoint. Data gathered in twarc can be imported into R for analysis as a dataframe if you export the data into CSV using twarc-csv."

[Here](https://pypi.org/project/twarc/) is the source.